# Session hijacking: Pros/Cons of a filter that suppresses Session IDs

Tags: java, security, session, cookies, servlets

I am trying to address session fixation/hijacking/sidejacking on an ATG/JBoss/Tomcat site.  It seems that by far, the most commons recommendations are:

1. Grant a new session to the user when they log in.  This prevents the attacker from being able to predict the session ID of the victim.  I tried this approach first, but I fear [it may not work in my case](https://community.atg.com/message/7213#7213)
2. Use a [servlet filter](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ai3zmw-OJAC0J%3arandomcoder.com/articles/jsessionid-considered-harmful+jsessionid+randomcoder&hl=en&gl=us&strip=1) to invalidate the session anytime a session ID (SID) is passed in the URL.  The filter additionally prevents url rewriting for creating links w/ SIDs

What are the pros and cons of #2?  Some that I've thought of:

**Pros**:

1. This seems like a broader protection than #1: #1 protects against malicious URLs being passed to the victim, #2 protects against any means of acquiring SIDs (insecure wireless networks, access to the machine, etc) - you can't just pass the SID you want to use a request parameter!

**Cons**:

1. Session management will be shot for users without cookies enabled.
2. Normal users will be logged out if they click a link w/ jsessionid specified, though I don't believe there will be any legitmate links like that in the system, due to the behavior of the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 is to stop [Session Fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation).

You also need to take [CSRF](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) aka "Session Riding" into consideration. [Here](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) are methods of preventing CSRF.

Finaly don't forget the most overlooked OWASP,  [OWASP A9 - Insufficient Transport Layer Protection](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection).  This means that your Session ID must be transmitted over HTTPS **at all times**.  If you don't then someone can use Firesheep to grab the account.

Comment: Good points.  Do the presence of these vulnerabilities count as a pro or con for approach #2? I noticed one common fix for CSRF is actually to use URL-rewriting, sigh.

Comment: @Adam Rabung they are unrelated.  I'm not sure how url-rewriting stops csrf... (http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: url rewriting would cause a unique id (valid session id) to be in the url, making it much harder to form a valid csrf link.  i think.

Comment: @Adam Rabung oah rewriting the urls on the page?  Sounds like a hack.

Answer (score 1):

You could store a variable in the session that contains the user's IP, user agent, etc. or a hash of them and check it every request so that if it is hijacked the hijackers would have to fake those.

Not perfect but it helps.

Comment: You're right - approach #2 really only defeats attackers who don't know how to forge headers.  This helps.

Comment: I tried the same, it creates problem when the user accesses the services through a proxy server and the proxy IP changes from one request to another. The IPs don't match and logged in legitimate users get logged out. It was a problem